# AWS ELB TCP http to https redirect with enabled proxy-protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes

I have an nginx-ingress and ELB with TCP:
[image]

I need TCP balancing because I use WebSocket.

nginx-ingress service annotations:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-draining-enabled: "true"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-draining-timeout: "60"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "3600"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: '*'
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:iam::<certificate arn>
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
```

I want to redirect all http to https. But if I set **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"** in annotations I would get redirect loop (TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).

How to redirect clients to HTTPS with enabled proxy-protocol?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I'm facing the same issue with one of my ingresses.

Comment: I've fixed it using custom http-snippet

https://gist.github.com/okgolove/91026dd104265a71095e8e0ace0f047a